# Using Vue Transition Group on Data Returned from Api Endpoint

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an api endpoint that I built that returns a list of products and everything there is working just fine. I tried to use this github link to get a working example because the endpoint I am using is not publicly available.

In my case, lets say we could hit this fictional endpoint: `https://api.github.com/orgs/vuejs/repos?id=123456`, one repo would be returned and what happens is it would appear immediately. How could we get the new items to fade in rather than immediately appearing on subsequent requests?

For the sake of this example, how could we make the repos fade in without actually wrapping the `v-if` element and the `v-else` element with `<transition>`? There should be a transition when `this.response = data` happens

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      response: null,
      loaded: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/vuejs/repos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.response = data;
          this.loaded = true;
       })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
}).mount('.repo-wrapper')
```

```css
.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
 }

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div class="repo-wrapper">
  <div v-if="!loaded" class="loading-wrapper">LOADING...</div>
  <div v-else>
    <transition-group name="fade">
      <div v-for="(repo, index) in response" :key="repo.id">
          <a :href="repo.html_url" :title="repo.description" target="_blank">
    {{ repo.name }}
          </a>
        </div>
       </transition-group>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use `index` as a `key`. Repo will change but index stays the same

Comment: Just updated the OP, this does not work, each time the data is set `this.response = data` the items appear with no fade in. I also read all about the hooks and the css classes but I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: There is no CSS in your code

Comment: Just added what I am using, still I don't know what is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `transition-group` is applying transitions to individual items of already rendered list. When you fetch your data, the list is not rendered at all as it is hidden after `v-else` and when it shows for the first time, that does not count as list change

See example below with changes:

1. `response` initial value is `[]` instead of null
2. `v-for` is rendered no matter if data is loaded or not

It works!

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      response: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchRandom() {
      this.fetchData(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))
    },    
    fetchData(pageSize = 10) {
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/orgs/vuejs/repos?per_page=${pageSize}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.response = data;
       })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
}).mount('.repo-wrapper')
```

```css
.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
 }

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div class="repo-wrapper">
  <button @click="fetchRandom">Reload</button>  
  <ul>
    <transition-group name="fade">
      <li v-for="(repo, index) in response" :key="repo.id">
          <a :href="repo.html_url" :title="repo.description" target="_blank">
    {{ repo.name }}
          </a>
        </li>
       </transition-group>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I was fighting with this forever and couldn‘t figure out what was going wrong.